# authorize.net payment gateway response issue

Tags: payment-gateway, authorize.net

I am having a problem with this Authorize.net payment gateway. I have specified the Default "Response/Receipt URLs" on merchant account. For this user need click on a link, to reach back to my website. How to do it automatically. I don't want to use relay url, it does not forward the url properly with css and js.

This is my code

```
<form method='post' name='authorizenet' action='$url' >
<input type='hidden' name='x_login' value='$loginID' />
<input type='hidden' name='x_amount' value='$amount' />
<input type='hidden' name='x_currency_code' value='USD' />
<input type='hidden' name='x_description' value='$description' />
<input type='hidden' name='x_invoice_num' value='$invoice' />
<input type='hidden' name='x_fp_sequence' value='$sequence' />
<input type='hidden' name='x_fp_timestamp' value='$timeStamp' />
<input type='hidden' name='x_fp_hash' value='$fingerprint' />
<input type='hidden' name='x_test_request' value='$testMode' />
<input type='hidden' name='x_show_form' value='PAYMENT_FORM' />
<input type='submit'  class='btn btn-lg btn-danger' value='$label' style='width:305px !important' />
```

Comment: Have you considered using [Accept.js](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html)?  It offers the ability for you to control the payment form UI but remove sensitive card data from touching your servers.

Comment: no I didn't, is it a separate process or related to SIM